# Find the length of the longest chain in a hierarchy

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy

I have hierarchical data being used to create an svg in my application. I need to find the length of the longest chain in that datasource. I could go through the datasource level by level, recursively going deeper into it to read _children, calling a recursive function to count the levels, but I am sure there must be a better way. This is further complicates because the datasource can go both directions from the node it starts on with _children and _parents.

```
var findChildren = function (ds, level) {
    if (!ds._children || ds._children.length == 0) {
        return level;
    }

    var longest = level + 1;
    ds._children.forEach(function (item) {
        var result = findChildren(item, level + 1);
        if (result > longest) {
            longest = result;
        }
    });
    return longest;
}
```

This is the function I am currently using, with an identical one that checks `ds._parents` to go the other way, passing the result of one as the starting level of the other. I am just sure there must be a better way...

For example, the same data could be in three ways, depending where the user opened the tree from.

1. `{"number":1,"type":"Delivery","_parents":[{"number":1,"type":"Order","_parents":[{"number":1,"type":"Quote"}]}]}`
2. `{"number":1,"type":"Order","_parents":[{"number":1,"type":"Quote"}],
   "_children":[{"number":1,"type":"Delivery"}]}`
3. `{"number":1,"type":"Quote","_children":[{"number":1,"type":"Order","_children":[{"number":1,"type":"Delivery"}]}]}`

Comment: Can you share the "hierarchical data"?

Comment: "but I am sure there must be a better way."  Why are you so sure?

Comment: Is `deepest` a typo for `longest`?  If not, where does it come from?

Comment: @ScottSauyet It is, I wrote it as deepest for deepest level before I realized I needed to go both ways so changed it to something that made more sense in both directions, longest.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I figure there must be functions intended for this, honestly I am a back end developer needing to handle some things in our system's front end, the duplicate question tells me that no there really isn't a much better way to do this.

Comment: I reopened this question because this is not exactly a duplicate: the question has the [tag:d3.js] tag and D3 has specific methods for that.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado then there are specific answers. The heirarchy is put into d3 systems after this.

Comment: I am writing an answer right now but I didn't understand what you said above: you don't want a D3 solution, is that correct?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado d3 solution is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you...

> need to find the length of the longest chain in that datasource.

That is the length going to the root to the deepest leaf in the data structure. There are convenient D3 methods to quickly find the deepest leaf.

So, suppose we have a hierarchical data like [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy):

```
{
    "name": "Eve",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Cain"
    }, {
        "name": "Seth",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Enos"
        }, {
            "name": "Noam"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Abel"
    }, {
        "name": "Awan",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Enoch"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Azura"
    }]
}
```

When you pass it to `d3.hierarchy()`...

```
var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data);
```

... it automatically creates a property named `depth` in each node:

> node.depth - zero for the root node, and increasing by one for each descendant generation.

So, we just need a simple function to get the biggest `depth` value. For instance:

```
var longest = d3.max(hierarchy.descendants().map(function(d) {
    return d.depth
}));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Eve",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Cain"
  }, {
    "name": "Seth",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Enos"
    }, {
      "name": "Noam"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Abel"
  }, {
    "name": "Awan",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Enoch"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Azura"
  }]
};

var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data);
var longest = d3.max(hierarchy.descendants().map(function(d) {
  return d.depth
}));
console.log("The longest chain has " + (longest + 1) + " levels.")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This definitely looks like it would solve half my issue, the issue is the datasource goes two ways, I may have `_children` and/or `_parents` from the 'root' of my datasource, is there any way to handle both?

Comment: A root has no parent. If your root has parents, it's not a root!

Comment: Technically the data is two trees goein either direction from the selected base object...

Comment: @Andrew in that case you have to share the data. Instead of editing this question, I suggest you post a new question, with the data (the two trees) and a clear description of the problem. If the data is too big, create two simple trees to work as examples.

Comment: I added to this question with a short example of the data, in three different possible configurations, which configuration depends on where the user starts (if the open from the 'order' they get option 2)